# Storm :Tick Tuple giving unexpected result

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-storm

I am running a storm topology, which writes the data into Cassandra DB and after an interval of every 15 min it copies the data from Cassandra to mongoDB.I am using `Tick-Tuple` for this purpose.When I start the topology it runs properly till first 15 min and writes the data to Cassandra after that all the data gets transferred into mongodb and is deleted from Cassandra. But , after that the data is not getting written into Cassandra. Though I will get all the data into my execute method and it doesn't throw any error as well.I checked the log as well, there is no error.

This is the execute method which inserts data into cassandra :

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

    String term = input.getString(0);
    int year = input.getInteger(1);
    int month = input.getInteger(2);
    int day = input.getInteger(3);
    int hour = input.getInteger(4);
    int dayofyear = input.getInteger(5);
    int weekofyear = input.getInteger(6);
    int productcount = input.getInteger(7);
    String sessionid = input.getString(8);

    /**
     * Inserting Values In Cassandra
     */

    BoundStatement insertUpdateTable = new BoundStatement(pStatement);
    insertUpdateTable.bind(sessionid, term, year, month, day, hour,
            dayofyear, weekofyear, productcount);

    session.executeAsync(insertUpdateTable);

    LOG.info(
            "Inserted data into table topquery:{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{} ",
            term, year, month, day, hour, dayofyear, weekofyear,
            productcount, sessionid);

}
```

This is Tick-Tuple :

```
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context) {

    KEYSPACE = stormConf.get(ApplicationConstants._CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE);
    LOG.info("KEYSPACE AT PREPARE METHOD IN TickTuple : {}", KEYSPACE);

}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    // configure how often a tick tuple will be sent to our bolt
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS);
    return conf;
}

protected static boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
    return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
            && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(
                    Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
}

@Override
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

    try {
        if (isTickTuple(input)) {

            ArrayList<String> sessionid = new ArrayList<String>();
            /**
             * Returns the List of Inactive SessionID.
             */
            sessionid = InactiveSessionIdTimeStampCassandra
                    .returnInactiveSessionId(KEYSPACE.toString());
            LOG.info("sessionid in TickTuple METHOD IN TickTuple : {}",
                    sessionid);
            /**
             * Exports the Data from Cassandra Tables to MongoDB based on
             * the SessionID returned by the
             * InactiveSessionIdTimeStampCassandra
             * .returnInactiveSessionId().
             */
            CassExport.cassExp(KEYSPACE.toString(),
                    TABLE_CASSANDRA_TOP_QUERY, KEYSPACE.toString(),
                    MONGO_COLLECTION_TopQuery, sessionid);
            LOG.info("cassEport in TickTuple METHOD IN TickTuple : {}",
                    KEYSPACE.toString());
            /**
             * Deletes the Data from the Cassandra Tables based on the
             * SessionID returned by the InactiveSessionIdTimeStampCassandra
             * .returnInactiveSessionId().
             */
            TruncateCassandraTable.truncateData(TABLE_CASSANDRA_TOP_QUERY,
                    sessionid, KEYSPACE.toString());

            LOG.info("In Truncate");
            //return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception in TickTuple", e);
    }

}
```

I am not able to figure out the cause.

Comment: The truncate table is an operation that can takes few seconds to be completed. It's possible that the input tick-tuple get timed out and it will be re-emit by storm. In such case, truncate table will be re-execute (infinite-loop).

Comment: The name of the function is truncate , but it is actually used for deleting the data based on the sessionid. 
` It's possible that the input tick-tuple get timed out and it will be re-emit by storm.`
 How can we set the timeout for ticktuple ?

Comment: You can edit the property 'topology.message.timeout.secs:' in storm.yaml the default is 30 seconds or Config.html#TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS. Actually this property is set for the entire topology and will be apply for your tuples too.